# View Frustum Culling corner cases

Tags: opengl, graphics, 3d

I was reviewing my view frustum culling code for a new OpenGL project I am working on, and was noticing a bit too many corner cases with large bounding volumes (e.g. spheres) and smaller frustums. Corner cases where the bounding volume is in no way intersecting will my frustum volume, yet getting accepted as visible. I am using the [Lighthouse3d](http://www.lighthouse3d.com/tutorials/view-frustum-culling/) method (geometric frustum plane method not radar) for extracting planes and testing against bounding volumes.

Here is an example (all frustum plane normals face inward (blue lines) )
http://img10.imageshack.us/img10/3970/70bm.jpg

The above image is top down, but neither the top or bottom frustum planes reject the sphere either.

This family of intersect methods rely on having at least one of the frustum planes reject the volume as outside. But there are corner cases where the volumes do not intersect, yet none of the frustum planes reject the volume, for example in the image I posted.

How does one deal typically deal with such cases (while still using world space frustum plane culling techniques, if possible)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because both are convex shapes, you can test intersection using the separating axis theorem (SAT) (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperplane_separation_theorem) to perform more correct testing.
With a box, this would usually mean inverting the test: test the frustum against the cube's various faces' planes (tho the original test is hopefully using a more efficient P/N test or so). With a sphere, you can construct a testing plane by connecting the sphere's centre to the frustum corner closest to it, which will be the plane's normal, and then placing it so it grazes the sphere. If that corner is on the negative side of the plane, it intersects. I edited your picture to illustrate this.

[image: Test plane constructed from corner and sphere origin]

[edited for clarification]

This will boil down to a simple "distance(corner, centre) > radius" test, but thinking of it in terms of SAT helps in more general cases.

To find the closest corner you can either simply test *all* corners, or you can use your previous plane test results to limit the corners to those contained by the frustum planes that intersected the sphere.

[/edit]

All in all, you'll want to decide whether or not the extra culling cost is really worth it, tho.

Comment: By offending corner do you mean the closest to the center of the sphere? And by testing the frustum against this do you mean all frustum corners against this new plane? I also need to do tests for large AABBs, but and i thing i know what you mean by inverting the test, but how would you do a pn-vertex like test for a frustum (how to find the p and n of the frustum)?

Comment: Yes, the closest point to the centre. I'll update the original post with some more sensible info. I was a bit careless explaining the AABB inversion (the P/N is the uninverted case, but you should be able to easily research the separating axis theorem on general polyhedra like this).